# Orchard CMS pages are crashing where there are input fields

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

In Orchard 1.8.1 I edited the /wwwroot/Core/Common/Views/EditorTemplates/Fields.Common.Text.Edit.cshtml file. But after uploading the file to the live site all the pages where we have input fields (forms) started to crash.
Throwing "The resource cannot be found." - 404 error.

I had a backup of the file which I downloaded before uploading the changed file.
I re-uploaded the backup file but still the issue exists on the site.

Is there any version mismatch or something?
Any idea what can fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the changes you had made?

In any case, it is better to make an alternate in your theme, rather than change the view in Core.